Cant add shared mailbox to SharePoint list people column
For some reason adding shared mail boxes to the person column in SharePoint have been blocked .  Does anyone have any information on this?
Is there a work around which isn't not using the people column?
See picture for specific error when I try to add the mailbox.
What I have tried:  https://camerondwyer.com/2021/05/17/problems-restricting-sharepoint-people-column-to-a-specific-group/ < This.  It doesn't help as I am not restricting the search group.
Any help would be appreciated.


Is the corresponding user account in AAD enabled?

You could check if the shared mailbox user in the Azure AD Users. If the user doesn't exist in the list, you could add the user in the list and check if you can add the user in the user field
